# Do we want that new users (rep 1) be able to post in GenAI SE Meta without having to post to the main site first?

Tags: discussion, private-beta, new-users, onboarding

Currently there is a banner sending users having questions about GenAI SE to GenAI Meta, i.e.,

> got a question about the site itself? genai.meta is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

[image: User registration - email confirmation]

But if a user has a reputation of less than 5 it will be sent to the main site, forcing the user to post a question that later might should be migrated to GenAI Meta.

Should we want this as part of the new users onboarding experience to GenAI SE?

> You must have at least 5 reputation on GenAI Stack Exchange to ask a question on meta, but you may ask a question about your own GenAI Stack Exchange post specifically.
> <sub>You do not currently have any posts on GenAI Stack Exchange; did you mean to [ask there](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?</sub>

[image]

Please bear in mind that there is per-meta-site setting for the minimal required reputation. The default value is 5. It could be set to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rep should be set to 1, at least for a little while.

GenAI is a unique site where we can experiment with rep thresholds to lower the barrier to participation. Especially given the possibility that a large group of users could come from outside the network and not be familiar with its norms it might be best to keep this barrier of participation low as well as others.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up (self-answered) question: [How to help new users to get started with GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/155/12)