# How to help new users to get started with GenAI SE?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Some individuals who are knowledgeable in fields related to GenAI Stack Exchange may struggle to understand the purpose and functioning of this community. The tour, the guidance on *Ask Question* page other places are still a "work in progress". What steps can we take to make the learning curve for *GenAI Stack Exchange* less challenging?

Meta requires +5 rep, and the chatroom requires +20 network rep. While there are "tricks" to get access to Meta, like including a link to a post and make submit edit suggestions, among others, these tricks might take a while to be caught by people new to the public Q&A platform.

Related

- [Do we want that new users (rep 1) be able to post in GenAI SE Meta without having to post to the main site first?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/57/12)
- [What guidance could we give to non tech savvy people struggling with using GenAI tools distributed through GitHub an alike plafforms?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Comment: Could you please provide some scenarios? IMHO, people who have questions, or answers to give, don't need much guidance. As a newcomer, I would struggle to understand what is Meta or why should I join a chatroom. People may need to join these spaces but only once they added a Q and A and have a question about the website.

Comment: @A.L : Some people are not "tech savvy", and some people are not familiar with how typical public Q&A platform users use computers and communicate with others but still be subject matter experts in fields related to Generative Artificial Intelligence. I.E., some people might not find the tour and might not look to secondary UI elements. Still, some users find their way to make a post and might get email notifications telling them they got an answer or a comment and are able to continue a conversation from there.

Comment: The public Q&A platform and the chosen wording for the UI elements and guidance look to be addressed to tech-savvy users familiar with specific Internet forums. Still, there are a lot of people that struggle with using web browsers, but, as I already said, might be able to provide valuable contributions if we make it easier for them to learn the ropes of GenAI Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -3):

One "crazy idea" that I have sought on Stack Overflow for Teams instances is to add a "question" to make it easier to get enough reputation to do certain tasks. In this case, we are looking to make it easier to get 20 reputation points to allow new users to participate in Meta and in the chatroom.

To avoid abuse

- new users should delete their answers to this post once they get enough reputation based on normal participation in the community,
- community moderators (at this time Staff) should do a periodical clean-up. They might look at this post a couple of times a day.

The title might be "Get Started in GenAI Stack Exchange". A link to this post might be added to the UI elements addressed to new users, like the tour, the banner shown pointing users to GenAI Meta, etc.

Users struggling to understand the GenAI Stack Exchange built-in guidance but finding their way to make a post might get the link through a comment if that post should not be upvoted.

This way the exception about how upvotes are given is contained to a single question instead of giving "empathy upvotes" on posts that don't meet the quality standards of GenAI Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to create an account on this community just to inform you that what you are suggesting is, in fact, voting fraud.

Comment: @TylerH Please elaborate. Better if you post a better alternative