# How should we handle "getting started" tutorials about GenAI tools? Let's say a getting started with Automatic111/stable-diffusion-web-ui

Tags: discussion

It looks that "Automatic1111" is used to refer to a popular GenAI tool. GenAI Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have several questions mentioning this word and are about [Automatic1111/stable-diffusion-web-ui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui). Many of them come from users who might benefit from a getting started guide explaining Stable Diffusion and the user (recommended knowledge and skills) and system requirements.

On the public Q&A platform, it's encouraged to post self-answered questions to share answers to questions we already know the answer but each post should be evaluated individually.

- Questions

  - According to the tour, questions should be about a practical, detailed problem. They should be about an **actual problem** that the question creator is facing.
- Answers

  - According to [/help/how-to-answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) only well-asked questions should be answered.

Some communities have made exceptions. Some require that a group of users work together on writing the question and answer and ask a Community Moderator to make the question a Community Wiki and agree that the answer creator makes it a Community Wiki.

Other communities use the tag wiki to post a list of resources or a getting started guidance.

Assuming that this community has a group of users willing to work together on creating a getting started guide with [Automatic1111/stable-diffusion-web-ui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui), should this getting started guide be handled on a tag wiki or as a self answered question?

Related

- [How to help new users to get started with GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/155/12)
- [What guidance could we give to non tech savvy people struggling with using GenAI tools distributed through GitHub an alike plafforms?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Comment: I just created a public Diigo Group and added to it a couple of links to Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion Web UI "getting started" stuff found on the web. I have not reviewed them. I might add comments to this bookmarks later. Here is the link to the group https://groups.diigo.com/group/genai-stackexchange